# Win 8.1 Excel 2013 not enough resources during data sort

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

**System**: 6 months old ASUS Ultrabook, 16 GB RAM, Win 8.1, Excel 2013

**File in question**: Excel spreadsheet (contact database, 14 columns 8,000 rows, nothing fancy, no percentages, all “General”, some color).

The problem first occurred last week.

During a routine Data Sort I got the following message:

> Cannot complete with available resources.

I have tried moving data - no luck, tried refreshing install (reset default and negating add-ins), changed printers and tried coping to another file - no luck.

Even tried a different PC and Windows 7 - no luck either.

Fortunately I found an older copy of the same contact sheet that worked, but is now showing similar problems.

I’m currently trying desperatly to move the contact data to Outlook.

I ran Webroot, Avira, Spybot, Malwarebytes with no hits.

Comment: **32-bit or 64-bit installation of Office?**

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2779852

When working with a Microsoft Excel File you receive one of the following messages:

> "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources. Choose less
>   data or close other applications."
>
> “Out of Memory”
>
> "Not enough System Resources to Display Completely"

Method 1: Contents of the spreadsheet ...

Method 2: Verify/install the latest updates ...

Method 3: Add-ins interfering  ...

Method 4: Test disabling Preview/Details Pane in Windows 7 ...

... and so long, 8 methods taken together :)